# How to sort array with nsstrings in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nsdate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NSArray of Dates sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1613863/nsarray-of-dates-sort)
>   [How to sort array having numbers as string in iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6097119/how-to-sort-array-having-numbers-as-string-in-iphone)

I have various NSDates which I am converting to NSString and storing it in an array.
I am trying to create sections according to the dates and I am sorting it at the same time.
I'm wondering if it is possible to sort an NSArray of NSStrings based on a number value, The array looks like :

```
Array: (
10AM,
12PM,
1PM,
3PM,
9AM
)
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be easier to just sort an NSArray of NSDates, you could just do

```
NSArray* sortedArray = [dateArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

sorting the strings themselves would get you into all types of strange situations...

Comment: Yeah true, but I have NSDate in different format like 2011-10-12 but I have to display the NSDate as sections using strings like 10AM or 8AM.

Comment: and? with am NSDateFormatter they are turned easily into Strings again.

Comment: @jbat : I am trying to compare NSDictionary of date arrays like self.dateArray = [[Dictionary allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)]; where allKeys include Array: (
10AM,
12PM,
1PM,
3PM,
9AM
)